# Pivot Table with Date as Column in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, pivot-table

I want to create pivot table where column candidate is from DATE column type.
Here is my table preview

[image: Table Preview]

And my expected result is like this :

```
MAIN_RESOURCE | MAIN_USER_NAME | 01-AUG-08 | 01-JUL-08 | 01-JAN-08 | 01-DEC-07 | 01-OCT-07 | next
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
08287060863     90000000000821       0          0           6565        109921      0        next
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

That values in each date column come from `TOTAL_AMOUNT`, `TOTAL_USAGE`, AND `INVOICE_DEBT`.
So, I must have three times of date columns. first for `TOTAL_AMOUNT`, second for `TOTAL_USAGE`, and the last one for `INVOICE_DEBT`.

How to create that?

Comment: It is not obvious what the listed values should represent.

Comment: Please elaborate your expected output. I can't figure out what goes into `Values here...` row- is that total of `total_amount`? Or `total_usage` or `invoice_debt`? Or total of all of these?